# How can I add a default value to a go text/template?

Tags: templates, go

I want to create a golang template with a default value that is used if a parameter is not supplied, but if I try to use the `or` function in my template,  it gives me this error:

```
template: t2:2:20: executing "t2" at <index .table_name 0>: error calling index: index of untyped nil
```

Here's an example of the code: https://play.golang.org/p/BwlpROrhm6

```
// text/template is a useful text generating tool.
// Related examples: http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#pkg-examples
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

var fullParams = map[string][]string{
    "table_name": []string{"TableNameFromParameters"},
    "min":        []string{"100"},
    "max":        []string{"500"},
}
var minimalParams = map[string][]string{
    "min": []string{"100"},
    "max": []string{"500"},
}

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    // Define Template
    t := template.Must(template.New("t2").Parse(`
        {{$table_name := (index .table_name 0) or "DefaultTableName"}}
        Hello World!
        The table name is {{$table_name}}
    `))
    check(t.Execute(os.Stdout, fullParams))
    check(t.Execute(os.Stdout, minimalParams))
}
```

Googling has pointed me towards an `isset` function in [hugo's template engine](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo), but I can't figure out how they implemented it, and I am not sure if it would even solve my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another solution is by changing the template definition to

```
// Define Template
t := template.Must(template.New("t2").Parse(`
    Hello World!
    The table name is {{with .table_name}}{{index . 0}}{{else}}DefaultTableName{{end}}
`))
```

But, the value won't be stored in a variable, so if you want to reuse it in other places, you need to write it again. The main purpose of the standard template package is for rendering *precomputed* value, and *logic* related operations/functions have limited capability. However, you can define your own `function` then register it to the template's [FuncMap](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#FuncMap) e.g. the `default` function mentioned by @jeevatkm.

Comment: It's certainly not pretty, but it works!  I think you're right about the intended purpose--I should probably be handing defaults outside of the template.  I will keep that in mind for a future revision of this project.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the function `or` in the template. This seems the simplest option.

```
{or .value "Default"}
```

From the docs:

```
or
        Returns the boolean OR of its arguments by returning the
        first non-empty argument or the last argument, that is,
        "or x y" behaves as "if x then x else y". All the
        arguments are evaluated.
```

https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions

[Playground Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/anYDRCJTk6t)

Comment: Granted that `.value` is always present, right?

Comment: To make it work with missing keys (at least under `docker`): `{{or (index . "Key") "Default"}}`.

Comment: I've included a demo, I hope that's some help. The docker environment should make no difference to how templates function.

Comment: What about [this one](https://play.golang.org/p/CWYTIWW4vi_3). And 'map has no entry for key "Slot"' is exactly what gives me Docker.

Comment: Right, I think see what you mean, yes if you're accessing a key in a map rather than a key in a struct you will need the syntax that you mentioned:

https://play.golang.org/p/loWbi4mbpL4

More mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152088/access-a-map-value-using-a-variable-key-in-a-go-template

This shouldn't have anything to do with Docker though.

Answer (score 2):

Go template does not have `default` function. However you can use library that provides `default` func.

For e.g.: `github.com/leekchan/gtf`

Refer here, how it is implemented at https://github.com/leekchan/gtf/blob/master/gtf.go#L28

---

Read hugo `isset` func [here](http://gohugo.io/templates/functions/) and source is [here](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/master/tpl/collections/collections.go#L368)