# Helm: Get value from a Map where the key is variable

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart as follows

```
dns_entries:
  cluster1: xx.xx.xx.xx
  cluster2: xx.xx.xx.xx
```

The cluster value is also set dynamically while installing the helm chart. In the templates, I need to choose this dynamically from the map above

```
{{- if hasKey .Values.dns_entries .Values.clusterId }}
  clusterIP: {{ .Values.dns_entries.{{ .Values.clusterId }} }}
  {{- end }}
```

How can I implement the above correctly ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that I needed to iterate over the map with built-in functions.

```
{{- if hasKey .Values.dns_entries .Values.clusterId }}
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.dns_entries }}
  {{- if eq $key .Values.clusterId }}
  clusterIP: $value
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: There is an easier way than this, see my answer

Answer (score 19):

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/

> `get`
>
> Given a map and a key, get the value from the map.

> `get $myDict "key1"`

```
get .Values.dns_entries .Values.clusterId
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved my case, where needed to base on two env variables: path of all envrionment database URLs and deployment environment.