# Kubernetes create a Map and get Values Dynamically

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I would like to create a map in value file and get the value depending of another variable.

For example :

```
resource[belgium] : 4G
resource[canada] : 4G
```

Then by passing the value belgium in environment variable COUNTRY, something like:

```
 {{ .Values.resource[$COUNTRY] }}
```

I don't find anything in the documentation.

Tx for help,

Gegko

Comment: Helm templates can't access environment variables, only the Helm values structure (but consider the `helm install -f` or `--set` options to dynamically pass options to it).  From there you can use the template `index` function, as [Access a map value using a variable key in a Go template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152088/access-a-map-value-using-a-variable-key-in-a-go-template) or [Helm: Get value from a Map where the key is variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734551/helm-get-value-from-a-map-where-the-key-is-variable).

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding the lookup in code and having a separate values file per environment, and then doing something like `helm install -f canada.yaml` to choose a specific set of configuration values.

Comment: The issue with this is that we have a lot of countries on 3 differents environment that means like 60 configuration files.

I will try the index solution ! Tx for your help !