# Helm template: get node of first array element

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, templating, go-templates

Say I have these values

```yaml
grafana:
  ...
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations: {}
      # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    hosts:
      - host: chart-example.local
        paths: ["/grafana"]
```

This is standard **helm**. For this reason, I would like to keep `hosts` as an array (even if it makes the following move a bit tricky). How can I get the first `.host` (I do not mind about any possible other) in order to make `env.value` dynamic

```yaml
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-grafana
          env:
          - name: GF_DOMAIN
            value: chart-example.local
```

I tried

```yaml
          env:
          - name: GF_DOMAIN
          {{- range .Values.grafana.ingress.hosts }}
            value: {{ .host }}
          {{- end }}
```

```yaml
          env:
          {{- range .Values.grafana.ingress.hosts }}
          - name: GF_DOMAIN
            value: {{ .host }}
          {{- end }}
```

Following [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52795357/7648881), I also tried

```yaml
          env:
          {{- with .Values.grafana.ingress.hosts 0}}
          - name: GF_DOMAIN
            value: {{ .host }}
          {{- end}}
```

or

```yaml
value: {{ .Values.grafana.ingress.hosts 0 .host }}
value: {{ .Values.grafana.ingress.hosts | first.host}}
```

How can I handle this case?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

What you need is the [`index` function](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions):

```yml
env:
{{- with (index .Values.grafana.ingress.hosts 0) }}
- name: GF_DOMAIN
  value: {{ .host }}
{{- end }}
```

Alternatively, [`first`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/lists.html) works just as well:

```yml
env:
{{- with (first .Values.grafana.ingress.hosts) }}
- name: GF_DOMAIN
  value: {{ .host }}
{{- end }}
```