# helm helpers file can't evaluate field type interface array/string

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am rather new to helm, and I am trying to create a chart, but running into values not transforming from the values.yaml file into my generated chart.

here are my values.yaml

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: name01
  namespace: ns-01
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-label
  jwtRules:
    - issuer: foo
      jwksUri: bar
      forwardOriginalToken: true
      audiences:
        - user1
        - user2
```

then with my helm template:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: name01
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.spec.selector.matchLabels.app }}
  jwtRules:
    - issuer: foo
      jwksUri: bar
      forwardOriginalToken: true
      audiences: |-
        {{- range .Values.spec.jwtRules.audiences }}
          - {{ . | title | quote }}
      {{ end }}
---
```

I also have a helpers file.

_helpers.tpl

```
{{/* vim: set filetype=mustache: */}}
{{- define "jwtRules.audiences" -}}
{{- range $.Values.spec.jwtRules.audiences }}
      audiences:
        - {{ . | quote }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

the error its producing: `at <.Values.spec.jwtRules.audiences>: can't evaluate field audiences in type interface {}`

Answer (score 2):

This one is simple - you don't have a `spec.jwtRules.audiences` in your values file! `jwtRules` contains an array, so you'll have to [use some index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64284395/helm-template-get-node-of-first-array-element) or iterate over it. Also, i don't think that neither your indentation, nor using of `|-` for audiences is correct, per [docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/jwt/) it should be an array of strings.

So i came up with this example (your values are unchanged):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: name01
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.spec.selector.matchLabels.app }}
  jwtRules:
    - issuer: foo
      jwksUri: bar
      forwardOriginalToken: true
      audiences:
      {{- with (first .Values.spec.jwtRules) }}
      {{- range .audiences }}
        - {{ . | title | quote -}}
      {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
```

renders into:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: name01
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-label
  jwtRules:
    - issuer: foo
      jwksUri: bar
      forwardOriginalToken: true
      audiences:
        - "User1"
        - "User2"
```

In this case it uses a first element of array

Comment: Hello @sype Consider accepting the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @andrew. I also came to a simple solution but would like feedback on it.

I removed the helpers file then modified my helm chart with the following.

values.yaml (is kept the same as above)

helmchart:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: name01
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.spec.selector.matchLabels.app }}
  jwtRules:
    - issuer: foo
      jwksUri: bar
      forwardOriginalToken: true
      {{- with index .Values.spec.jwtRules 0 }}
      audiences:
         {{- range $a := .audiences }}
         - {{ $a -}}
      {{ end }}
      {{ end }}
---
```

This produces the following:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: name01
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-label
  jwtRules:
    - issuer: foo
      jwksUri: bar
      forwardOriginalToken: true
      audiences:
         - user1
         - user2
```

Should I continue to use a helpers file?

Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: helpers usually help to eliminate boilerplate and also helpful when you have a lot of extra conditions, which alter your output significantly depending on some values. Check default `_helpers.tpl` to get an idea when they are used. In your case, however, hiding your implementation of audiences will hamper readability for others, and since you won't be reusing this code in other templates - i think it's better to not use helpers in this case. 

Also, welcome to StackOverflow, and please, create a separate question if original one is answered, and don't use answer section for questions. Ty!

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome. I appreciate you and your thorough answers.