# How do I pass a range operator a list value built with a variable for a helm template?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have a template file like the one below.

```
{{- $appName := include "template-name.camelcase" . }}
{{- range $versions := .Values.domain.$appName }}
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind:Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $appName }}-{{ $versions.environment }}
---
{{- end }}
```

It doesn't seem to take the **$appName** variable that I've appended to **.Values.domain.** If I replace **$appName** with a hardcoded value that contains a list of values then helm will build the template. Is there a different syntax or way I should go about passing the list to the range operation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access a map value using a variable key in a Go template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152088/access-a-map-value-using-a-variable-key-in-a-go-template)

Comment: Use `index .Values.domain $appName` to do the dynamic lookup (as the expression part of the `range` statement).

Comment: This `{{- range $versions := index .Values.domain $appName }}` ended up working for me